# change background onclick with class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have few buttons, all with same class='background'. 
Now I'm using this to change the background colour of button onclick.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".background").click(function(){
        $('.background').css('background','rgba(0,0,0,0.2)');
    });
});
</script>
```

But this is changing background of all the buttons. How can I change background of the button which is clicked. 
NOTE: I've to do this without using id

Answer (score 2):

Use `this` object.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".background").click(function(){
        $(this).css('background','rgba(0,0,0,0.2)');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use context `this` in clicked event to only target currently clicked element:

```
$(".background").click(function(){
    $(this).css('background','rgba(0,0,0,0.2)');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".background").click(function(){
        $(".background").css('background',''); // Reset background color of other buttons
        $(this).css('background','rgba(0,0,0,0.2)'); // Set backgroundcolor of this button
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/4xye20n6/)